# Is there a way to get Views Bulk Operation to place field options in the main VBO exposed dropdown

Tags: 7, views

I am using VBO to set the author for a one of my content types.  Currently, when you want to use the change author page, you have to..

1. Navigate to the page.
2. Select the target content items
3. Select 'Change Author' from the VBO drop down list (this is the only option)
4. Wait for the new page to load
5. Select the new author form the (only) drop down lost on this page.
6. Submit

It seems that there are a lot of extra steps here.  Is there a way to set-up the primary VBO drop down list (refereed to in step 3) so that it displays the different authors (like the drop down refereed to in step 5?)

Answer (score 2):

If you check the "Skip confirmation step" box below the "Change the author of content" action, you can remove the confirmation step.

As for making it a one-click change, that would probably require either extending VBO with another module, or somehow invoking ctools modal windows with VBO. I haven't found any success stories with the latter, but there's this: [Ctools Modal + Views Bulk Operations? (drupal.org)](https://drupal.org/node/1155896)

Comment: Just remembered the "Colorbox trigger" field (requires Colorbox module). I was curious and added it to a view display and chose "Content" (my VBO field) as my trigger. Unfortunately, when I check one or more rows and invoke a VBO action, the only result is a blank colorbox. But still, this could be promising. There's also a Lightbox trigger and I wouldn't be surprised if there were a Fancybox trigger.  I probably won't experiment much more on this any time soon, but thought I'd throw this out there.